# How can I do Qt QLed signal slot connection?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I want to connect led with signal slots. When the led status changed i want to do something. Here by signal slot code;

```
QLed*        ledAliveStatus;
connect(ledAliveStatus, SIGNAL(valueChanged(bool)), this, SLOT(CheckConfiguration(bool)));
```

When i debug the program, it gave me

**Object::connect: No such signal QLed::valueChanged(bool)**

The Qled class signal slots methods can be seen the below. I tried to LedStateChaned(bool) instead of value changed but it gave me the same error.

```
// User-defined attributes

signals:
void ledStateChanged(bool);
void ledRotationChanged(double);
void ledStateToggled();

public slots:
void setLedState(const bool &ledState);
void setLedStretch(const bool &ledStretch);
void setLedShape(const LedShape &ledShape);
void setLedType(const LedType &ledType);
```

Comment: How QLed class look like?

Comment: This is a qt class, i didn't wrote it.

Comment: I cannot see it in qt5, which version are we talking about?

Comment: are you using this? http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/QLed+?content=72482

Comment: I just realize that we are using own QLed class and i added to signal slots code see the edit.

Comment: Well the problem is obvious. There is no `QLed::valueChanged(bool)` signal. There is `QLed::ledStateChanged(bool)` however.

Comment: Look at the signals. There is no `valueChanged(bool)`. But there is a `ledStateChanged(bool)`. So, use signals that exist..

Comment: The Qled class signal slots methods can be seen the below. I tried to LedStateChaned(bool) instead of value changed but it gave me the same error.

Comment: `valueChanged` isn't there and you're wondering about the error. `ledStateChanged` on the other hand is, but **you have to type it right in the first place, not with capital L. And stop using `Q` as prefix for your own classes, stop using old way to connect signals and slots.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no signal named `valueChanged()`. You should use

```
connect(ledAliveStatus, SIGNAL(ledStateChanged(bool)), this, SLOT(CheckConfiguration(bool)));
```